# Laravel Nested DB Transactions

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, transactions

I did some diging on Laravel Nested Transactions but still i am very confused , Basically in my code i have a one calling function which called multiple other functions and called functions becomes calling and they called other multiple functions etc eg

```
public function A()
{
    $this->B();
    $this->C();
}

public function B()
{
    $this->D();
    $this->E();
}

public function C()
{
    $this->F();
}
```

the thing i want to achive is that whenever DB exception occur i want to rollback all the transactions in calling and called functions, so i just want to know where i have to begin transactions and end, mean weather i should begin transaction in each individual function or at root function and also how to pass exception from called function to calling function, hope so you guys will get my point

Comment: If you wrap your code in `DB::transaction(function ...)` then Laravel should handle things for you.

Comment: thanks for your precious time and help, so you want me to have only one Db transaction begin in Function A which is a calling function and whenever an exception occurs in called function (etc B(), C()) than i should return it calling function and rollback all the transaction.

`public function A()
{
DB::transaction(function () {
 $this->B();
 $this->C();
});
}

public function B()
{
 $this->D();
 $this->E();
}

public function C()
{
 $this->F();
}`
so than this shold work if i am correct

Comment: If an exception occurs and is unhandled all transactions should be rolled back.  However if you do `function B() {  try { $this->D(); } catch(Exception $e) { /* do something */ } $this->E(); }` then if `D()` throws an exception only the transaction within `D` will  be rolled back assuming there is nested transaction support, which MySQL does have with InnoDB I think. If your DBMS does not have nested transaction support then Laravel actually only starts a single transaction so in that case you may have some inconsistent behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do

```
public function A()
{
    $this->D();
    $this->E();
    $this->F();
}
```

that way you can put `DB::transaction(function ...)` on all 3 `A()`, `B()` and `C()`